# Website fit on screen for tablets, viewport not working?

Tags: php, android, html, css

I've built a webshop with opencart, with a theme that was originally responsive. However, the owner wanted exactly the same website on all platforms, so I simply removed a seperate responsive.css file and fixed the issue. However, I would like the website to fit on screen
when I open it on my tablet. That isn't working though. I have this in the header of my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Shouldn't that fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What does “isn't working” mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Nope, the strange thing is, even though you tell it that simply no zoom is possible. When I open the page I can still zoom out to the level that it fits on screen and zoom in to the intials level. Other than that, nothing..

Comment: then put your website width instead of device width eg. <meta name="viewport" content="width=800"> @user2704687

Comment: That did fix it!! Thanks. Strange though that 'device width' wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below meta code hope it will solve your issue

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: This indicates that if the user for some reason is running IE in compatibility mode for the page, you will override this by setting the X-UA-Compatible=EDGE. This means that if you know that your page will be displayed best using the latest standards, you can force IE to run in edge mode even if the user has activated compatibility mode.

As a bonus effect on this, IE will also hide the compatibilty button in the address bar when yo have set X-UA-Compatible=EDGE.

Comment: I know what that means, I was wondering WHY this would solve OP's problem and WHY this would relate to that (OP's talking about mobile rendering, on a tablet, and - by looking at the tags - using android)