# viewport device-width no longer works in edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a CSS solution to prevent ms edge from zooming a web page when the browser is "snapped" to one side of the screen. currently when snapped it zooms out and everything is smaller. I want it to stay the same size.

adding the following CSS used to work:

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
```

but with the latest version of edge (I'm using 38) it doesn't work anymore

I've found the following posts that talk about this issue in some way:

[Website fit on screen for tablets, viewport not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192066/website-fit-on-screen-for-tablets-viewport-not-working)

[Disable all page-zooming in IE11 on Windows8-Arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757403/disable-all-page-zooming-in-ie11-on-windows8-arm)

but neither solve the problem. edge still changes the zoom on snap. adding the viewport meta tag to the head doesn't have any effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it's been momentarily and voluntarily disabled by the Microsoft Edge team, apparently due to compatibility conflicts. See this [@-ms-viewport bug tracker issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7970618/) with a discussion.